# How to change anchor text when a method has finished running in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, function, button, methods, anchor

I have a `<a href>` link and a function that changes the innerHTML of the link from 'Update' to 'Loading...' when the link is clicked (acting as a button).

An alert dialog appears when the function has run successfully, but the text remains as 'Loading...'. How can I check that the method has finished and change the text back to its initial 'Update' text?

```
<a href="#" id="myID" class="button1">Update</a>

$('#myID').on('click', function () {
    $(this).text("Loading...");

    method();
    return false;
});
```

I can get the text to revert back by putting `$(this).text("Update");` in the method() itself but this is messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a [callback function](http://www.impressivewebs.com/callback-functions-javascript/) into method:

```
function method( callback ){
    // do something...
    callback();
}
```

Then call using:

```
$('#myID').on('click', function () {
    $(this).text("Loading...");

    method( function(){ $('#myID').text('Update'); } );
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can done with this.

```
 <a href="#" id="myID" class="button1">Update</a>

$('#myID').on('click', function () {
    $(this).text("Loading...");

    method(callback(){
       $('#myID').text("done with Loading...");});
    return false;
});   

function method(callback){
 if (typeof callback === "function") {
           callback();
    }
}
```